# Cross Namespace Object Orientation?

Tags: php, namespaces

Whilst developing an object-orientated HMVC that has a super-object, at some point during the application process, it required the utilisation of namespaces. Here, namespaces will act as a method of "versioning" different code that can be accessed the same way. In the scaled down example below, I am able to execute the class `Foo` with the method `qux` if I am in version `A` or `B`. I understand that if I utilise `self::` rather than `$this` the problem will disappear, however, I wish to avoid this. At the moment, I get the following PHP error:

`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

So my question is, how can I use `$this` in this particular context?

```
namespace
{
    $gamma = new \Gamma();
    $gamma->execute('A', 'Foo', 'qux');

    // ...

    class Alpha
    {
        // ...
    }
    class Beta extends Alpha
    {
        public function foo($input)
        {
            echo $this->bar($input);
        }
        public function bar($input)
        {
            return $input;
        }
    }
    class Gamma extends Beta
    {
        public function execute($space, $class, $method)
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($space . '\\' . $class, $method), array());
        }
    }
}
namespace A
{
    class Foo extends \Gamma
    {
        public function qux()
        {
            $this->foo('I like turtles');
        }
    }
}
namespace B
{
    class Foo extends \Gamma
    {
        public function qux()
        {
            $this->foo('I like strawberries');
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

```
"I like turtles"
```

Any advice, answers, guidance are much appreciated. :3

Comment: This make no sense. You cannot use `$this` in static context. You should not use methods as static, if they are not explicitly defined as such. And you should not be "doing work" in the constructors.

Comment: @tereško I am asking how it is a static context, how to avoid it being a static context and it is only an example.

Comment: You really shouldn't call functions on extended classes; the parent is not supposed to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I was passing the class via the `call_user_func_array` function statically. Therefore, I was unable to use `$this`. Thus, an initiation of the requested class would be required, and passed through as a variable, like so:

```
// ... Continuing from Beta::execute() ...
$class = $space . '\\' . $class;
$class = new $class();
call_user_func_array(array($class, $method), array());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what abstract methods are for.

You should declare `Master` as an abstract class, and `qux` as an abstract method:

```
abstract class Master
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->qux();
    }
    abstract public function qux();
}

class Foo extends Master
{
    public function qux()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```